onSchedule firebase function not deploying
When executing firebase deploy all my onRequest functions are deploying correctly but scheduled functions are not uploading after upgrading to 2nd gen firebase function. What im missing?
Im importing the 2nd gen lib:


const {onSchedule}
    = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");



My code looks like:

EDIT: when I deploy to firebase functions with the CLI (command: firebase deploy) only onRequest functions deploy to prod, no error appears, it looks like if the onSchedule function doesn't exist.
thanks

What do you mean by "not deploying"?  What exactly are you observing that's different than what you expect?  Is there an error?  Something in logs?  Please edit the question to be clear about what you are doing to reproduce this.  We should be able to copy your code and instructions to get the same result.

Also, on Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

question edited

Would you like the share the output of the CLI that clearly shows that the scheduled function wasn't deployed, but the others were?  I also suggest editing the question to show the complete minimal code you're trying to deploy as formatted text, not as a picture, so we can easily copy what you have and reproduce the same result.

I'm facing the exact same issue right now. Scheduled functions were deploying normally but as of now - all HTTP triggered functions are updated but the scheduled functions are no-where to be seen. This is both in Firebase Console and in Cloud Functions (where they were showing previously). I deleted them as the deployment logs output were complaining that they didn't exist within my code but they did. Nothing was changed. Starting to think it might be a GCP issue

@KieranGoodary Then you should reach out to Firebase support directly.  The volunteers of Stack Overflow will be of no help without specific instructions to reproduce, and even then we are not able to diagnose problems with closed source hosted services.

@mmsergi okay - i managed to solve the issue, it could be that i caught the deployment at a bad time, not sure - but my functions got stuck in some state where they could not be detected by firebase deploy --only functions. To resolve this, i manually deleted from Cloud Functions, double checked in Cloud Scheduler. It is worth noting that for a small period of time - deleting functions were not functioning well. I then redeployed from my own terminal. This time they deployed. No code changed - just a blip in GCP. Worth checking latest library versions etc. cc: @doug-stevenson
